# How do I collect this collectable in "Is it safe to ride?"?

Tags: quantum-conundrum

I 'need' to reach the space above the exit door to collect the awkward noise generator on the table, but I can't just stack the assorted furnishings as the fan will blow any lightened objects to the right.

[image: The room]

How do I reach the collectable?

The puzzle is the third part of 'Is it safe to ride?' just after the bit where you throw the safe and then jump on it.

Comment: I can't remember that puzzle exactly (the puzzle / chapter name could help :), so I don't know if you've reached the bit of the game that teaches you this trick (or if it's even possible in the context of this puzzle) -- but can you throw a piece of furniture (in fluffy dimension) from the position the image was taken from and then (very, very quickly) switch to the slow dimension, hop on the thrown item and ride it across the gap?

Comment: Yeah, I got stuck at the same point,and haven't been back to the game in about a week.

Comment: Ronan, wrt your edit - `although that trick doesn't seem to work here.` - why not? I don't have the game handy at work, so just curious, as it seems like the obvious action (especially if you're in the section of the game that just taught you that trick).

Comment: @DMA57361 Apparently it does, I was just doing it wrong.

Comment: Ah cool, you've laid hands on it then? :) Guess I'll throw down an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember that puzzle exactly, so I don't know if it's possible in the context of this puzzle, but it seems like the most logical solution given you're in the bit of the game that teaches you this trick, so try the following:

1. In the *Fluffy* Dimension pick-up a piece of furniture (a table is ideal) and move to the position shown in the image.
2. Throw the piece of furniture so that it fly over to the location of the collectable.
3. **Very quickly** switch to the *Slow* Dimension.
4. Jump on the thrown piece of furniture.
5. Wait for the furniture to finish it's journey, delivering you to the collectable.
   You might have to jump the last bit of the gap yourself.

If this gives you trouble because you can't get a high enough arc on the thrown object while still being able to jump on it, then you might be able to pull off the trick by instead throwing the object from as far back on the ground level as possible (with a higher arc) then running around to the top level and jumping on to it then (you'd need to swap to *Slow* very quickly after throwing) - without having the game here to test, though, I'm not sure which of the two presents the most reliable approach.

Comment: And remember, normal is a dimension as well.

Comment: Indeed. I assume you're pointing out you don't have to wait for the furniture to complete it's entire journey in *Slow*..? Otherwise, I'm not sure what your point is?

Comment: I found that a chair to help you jump onto the table is effective.

Comment: @DMA57361: Yes, exactly.  It's been a while, but I have a feeling _Slow_ might be too slow.

Comment: I just did this one a few weeks ago and if you don't do it in slow you may end up missing the jump if the thrown table falls short

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is use a similar tactic  as riding the safe but I would recommend using a table.  First pick up your landing object in fluffy dimension standing a little ways back from the edge and hit the slow time dimension shortly after it crosses the end of the walk way there.  Jump on your object while still in slow time dimension and you should be able to ride about half-way across the room before having to jump again and you should be able to make it.

I know getting this object took me several tries and lots of swearing trying to get the timing down right.